# KDE plasma disappear panel settings

Tags: linux, kde, manjaro, plasma

My KDE plasma has multiple problems:

1. When I open panel settings, clicked on one setting option, the settings disappear and don't get applied.

In the bottom screenshot I opened setting of panel :

[image: see panel settings in this screenshot]

but after I click on any button in this setting panel, settings disappear !!

2. It does not open search panel in top of desktop (alt+space is a shortcut to open this search box).when I pressing `alt`+`space`, the search box just appear for 50ms and again disappear !!

[image: screen shot of search box that doesn't appear for me]

3. When I open an application, I can see that the application is opened and the icon appears in the bottom panel. But the application itself doesn't show up, and I have to click on the application icon in the bottom panel to get it to show up.

   - OS : Manjaro .
   - KDE plasma version 5.11.2
   - KDE Framework version is 5.39.0

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. I don't understand what you are asking, and your video is hosted on a service that will delete the file in four weeks. Please take some screenshots and upload them via this interface instead, so that they will persist in the future. I also don't understand the last problem, so a screenshot may also help to clarify this.

Comment: @Sparhawk thanks for your welcome ;) .
I removed video and added screenshots and also edited my third question.

Comment: The first two are clear to me now (although I can't answer the question), but I'm still not sure what you mean in #3 ("for see application my self should click on"). I've retracted my close vote anyway.

Comment: @Sparhawk I think I got it, and tried to clarify.

Comment: @JennyD Thanks, yes that seems right on re-reading.

Comment: @JennyD Thanks.yes I want to say that for question #3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it , all of issues caused by setting "focus stealing prevention"
option on "Extreme" (All windows must be explicitly activated by the user) . should setting on "Medium" for normal behavior .

Thanks to @PeterFleix for his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/627288/770776)

[About focus stealing prevention level](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/windowbehaviour/index.html)